# If I am on a business visa to UK from India and want to travel to Italy, which visas to apply for?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and planning for a business trip to UK from where I plan to join my family for a vacation in Italy and come back to UK for business. What visas should I apply for? Business visa for UK but then from where do I get my Schengen visa to Italy?

Answer (score 2):

On next Friday (24 April 2015), the UK Business Visitor visa will be abolished and will not exist after that date.

Instead you can apply for the new Visitor (general) visa.  This visa permits the holder to engage in both tourism and business activities.  To apply, you can create an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/).

You can apply for a Schengen visa in India at the [Visa Facilitation Service](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/delhi/shortterm.html).

Comment: @Abhi, no need for thanks, it's all part of the service; please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Visa4UK is actually a foreign office thing? It sounds like a scam company that charges you double to just pass your paperwork on. Well done FCO...

Comment: @CMaster, no, it's their site for on-line applications